# Why cannot I set the value attribute of texarea by setAttribute?

Tags: html, textarea

```
<textarea value="hello" id="id1"></textarea>
```

The above textarea does not show "hello" in it.

```js
document.getElementById('id1').setAttribute("value", "hello");
```

```html
<textarea value="hello" id="id1"></textarea>
```

This textarea  does not show "hello", either. But the following one does show "hello" in it, why?

```js
document.getElementById('id1').value = "hello";
```

```html
<textarea value="hello" id="id1"></textarea>
```

The `setAttribute` works perfectly for `<input>` element:

```js
document.getElementById('id1').setAttribute("value", "hello");
```

```html
<input value="" id="id1" />
```

Comment: @mplungjan but why document.getElementById('id1').value="hello"; works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) does not have a value attribute to set using setAttribute - it has a value property you set directly using the element.value

Compare

```
<textarea>value</textarea>
```

to

```
<input value="value"/>
```

where value is an attribute of the input element

Answer (score 2):

In DOM, `input` and `textarea` elements have a `defaultValue` property. This controls what is displayed in the element if the user doesn't type anything or if the form is reset.

For an `input` element the `defaultValue` property maps onto the `value` **attribute**.

For a `textarea` element the `defaultValue` property maps onto the **text content** of the element. `textarea` elements do not have a `value` **attribute**.

---

Both kinds of element have a `value` **property** which represents the **current** value.

That this has the same name as the input elements `value` **attribute** is unfortunate and a source of a fair bit of confusion.